# How to properly align icon and text in a table?

Tags: css, html, html-table, tablelayout

I am having trouble trying to vertically align the icon with the text. Basically, I'm trying to have the image icon to the top of the `<td>` tag, right now, it's in the middle as shown in the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/N6fLp/

I put `border:1px dotted blue;` to see clearly where each element is being spaced. By default, the `td` tag that wraps the `img` tag is centered. How do I put the img tag and title header to the very top of the table's `td` tag and align adjacently with the text?

I tried to imitate the result by putting `vertical-align:text-top` but that didn't work. I also tried `position:relative` to the table and then setting the image to `top:0;` but to no avail that didn't work either. What am I missing here?

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://www.newtekinsurance.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/icon-audience.png" alt="img.png"/></td>
        <td>
            <strong>Title header</strong>
            <br>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
            <ul class="arrowLink">
                <li><a href="javascript:showNotice('#')">View Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://www.newtekinsurance.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/icon-audience.png" alt="img.png"/></td>
        <td>
            <strong>Title Header</strong><br>
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
            <ul class="arrowlink">
                <li><a href="javascript:showNotice('#')">View Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://www.newtekinsurance.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/icon-audience.png" alt="img.png"/></td>
        <td>
            <strong>Title Header</strong><br>
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
            <ul class="arrowlink">
                <li><a href="javascript:showNotice('#')">View Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://www.newtekinsurance.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/icon-audience.png" alt="img.png"/></td>
        <td>
            <strong>Title Header</strong><br>
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

            <ul>
                <li>Hola <a href="javascript:showNotice('#')">Google</a><br>
                    <br>
                </li>

                <li>Include completed <a href="#" target="_blank">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>

            <p>Mail to:<br>
            Lorem Ipsum<br>
            Attn: Lorem Ipsum<br>
            1234 Main Street<br>
            NY NY 12345</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://www.newtekinsurance.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/icon-audience.png" alt="img.png"/></td>
        <td>
            <strong>Title Header</strong><br>
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://www.newtekinsurance.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/icon-audience.png" alt="img.png"/></td>
        <td>
            <strong>Title Header</strong><br>
            Lorem <a href="javascript:showNotice('#')">Lorem</a> website Lorem ipsum

            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>

            <p class="small">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{border:1px dotted blue;}
ul,li{padding-left:15px !important;padding:0;margin:0;}
/*table, tr, td, p{margin:0;padding:0;}*/
img{margin-right:10px;}
img{width:50px;height:50px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To vertically align an element to the top of a table cell, you can use the CSS `vertical-align:top` definition.

```
td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/N6fLp/1/)

Answer (score 1):

i tried this in your jsfiddle and i only add this

```
td {
    padding: 6px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

to the css

Answer (score 1):

It is generally an old style using tables and gives you limited functionality.
if you choose to use a table you can either add to the html code where needed:

```
<td valign="top"><img ... /></td>
```

or use css (this will affect all td's):

```
td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

if  you choose not to use tables, I would recommend reading this article:

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <td><img /></td>
   <td>Text</p>
</div>
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```